# Handling variable payloads with AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, aws-lambda

I'm looking to build some lambdas in C# to cater for certain events coming out of Cognito.

I don't have classes for the event payload so thought I would just create a generic interface and work from there.

As such, I defined my entry point for the lambda as

```
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace FCKM_PostAuth_01;

public class Function
{
    public string FunctionHandler(JObject request, ILambdaContext context)
    {
       // LambdaLogger.Log($"JObject: {request.ToString()}");

        return "OK";
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this fails on execution (via the AWS test harness) with the following

```
System.Exception: Error deserializing the input JSON to type JObject
   at Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.Runtime.LambdaExecutor.BuildParameters(ExecutionRequest request, ILambdaContext context) in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src868358059\src\Tools\LambdaTestTool\src\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool\Runtime\LambdaExecutor.cs:line 215
   at Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.Runtime.LambdaExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ExecutionRequest request) in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src868358059\src\Tools\LambdaTestTool\src\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool\Runtime\LambdaExecutor.cs:line 52
---------------- Inner 1 Exception ------------
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.Runtime.LambdaExecutor.BuildParameters(ExecutionRequest request, ILambdaContext context) in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src868358059\src\Tools\LambdaTestTool\src\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool\Runtime\LambdaExecutor.cs:line 203
---------------- Inner 2 Exception ------------
Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.JsonSerializerException: Error converting the Lambda event JSON payload to type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject: The JSON value could not be converted to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken. Path: $.version | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 14.
   at Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.AbstractLambdaJsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream requestStream)
---------------- Inner 3 Exception ------------
System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken. Path: $.version | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 14.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_DeserializeUnableToConvertValue(Type propertyType)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter`2.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, TCollection& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonDictionaryConverter`3.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, TDictionary& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, Nullable`1 actualByteCount)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer.InternalDeserialize[T](Byte[] utf8Json)
   at Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.AbstractLambdaJsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream requestStream)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer` can't deserialize to a `JObject`; for that, you should instead use `Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer`:

```cs
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
```